# How can you turn off text highlighting (hlsearch) with custom text objects?

Tags: visual-mode, cursor-motions, custom-text-object

I am implementing a custom text object in visual mode, but this text object uses regular expressions to find the beginning and ending of the selection. However, when I do this, other parts of the text are also hilighted. As an additional problem, the searches are added to my search history.

How can these two things be avoided?

**EDIT**

I'm trying to creating a visual-mode text object, determining the start and end position using the search backward (`?`) and search forward (`/`) operators, similar to the following (the regular expression is just a test for now).

```
vnoremap ue ?[^a-zA-Z0-9]\\|^<cr>v/[a-zA-Z0-9]\+/e<cr>
```

When `ue` is pressed in visual mode:

1. The above searches backwards for a character that is not `a-z`, `A-Z` or `0-9` or until the beginning of the line. This is the text `?[^a-zA-Z0-9]\\|^<cr>`.
2. It then enters visual mode with `v`.
3. It then searches forward for the last character that is `a-z`, `A-Z` or `0-9`. This is text `/[a-zA-Z0-9]\+/e<cr>`.

The above works fine, but ends up highlighting all characters in the last search expression (step 3). I've tried appending `:noh<cr>` to the mapping, but this causes the selection to be lost. How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you look at `:h search()`?

Comment: The only complication with `search()` might be getting it to take a count if that's a requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you turn off search highlighting, use `gv` to reselect the previous visual selection.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using a function because it's easier to read, but `gv` works, and looks like an excellent little command for my tool belt. Cheers.