# How to search in visual mapping?

Tags: cursor-motions, visual-mode

I am trying to create a text object for consecutive lower-case letters.

Here is how I am setting up the inner text object:

```
xnoremap in :<C-u>normal! ?[^a-z]?e+1<CR>v/[^a-z]/s-1<CR>
onoremap in :normal vin<CR>
```

The following shows what happens when I type `vin`:

```
[text]               some important text
[cursor]                       |
[expected selection]      ^^^^^^^^^
[actual selection]             ^^^^
```

I then tried the following with the same text and cursor position:

```
v:<C-u>normal! ?i
```

The cursor didn't move.  I expected it to.

Searching forward doesn't work either:

```
v:<C-u>normal! /t
```

However all these work:

```
v:<C-u>normal! b
v:<C-u>normal! e
v:<C-u>normal! Fi
v:<C-u>normal! ft
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: This is similar to [How can you turn off text highlighting (hlsearch) with custom text objects?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/12487/1643) but after reading it I'm still stuck ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the `<CR>` in your mapping signals to the *norm command* to finish, not for the the `?` command to finish. So when you get to the first `<CR>`, the command that vim runs is

```
normal! ?[^a-z]?e+1
```

And this command *does not do anything*. Because you don't hit enter by the time the normal command is over, nothing actually happens. So here we have a dilemma. We need to tell vim to press enter *inside of* the normal command, but we can't press enter (because that finishes the normal command). Here is where we use `<C-v>` to enter a literal carriage return.

So you need to put a `<C-v>` before every `<CR>` that is not the final `<CR>` in your command. This makes the following mapping:

```
xnoremap in :<C-u>normal! ?[^a-z]?e+1<C-v><CR>v/[^a-z]/s-1<C-v><CR><CR>
onoremap in :normal vin<CR>
```

---

Some unrelated side notes about your approach:

1. This approach only works if you're in the middle of your object. If you're at the beginning of it, things break.
2. Using `\L` is equivalent to `[^a-z]`, and is faster and more readable.

Comment: Thanks for both the clear explanation and the side notes.  All much appreciated!

Comment: My pleasure! Glad to help. :)

Comment: Preceding the initial backward search (`?`) with `l` to move right one character seems to solve note 1.

Comment: @AndyStewart Yes, but that causes a new problem: It doesn't work if you're at the end of your object.

Comment: Why not?  If you're on the last lower case letter, moving 1 character right then searching backwards will start the search on the last lower case letter.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think about that. Good point