# Regexp for beginning of word?

Tags: regular-expression

I am trying to search backwards (using `?`) for the beginning of a "word".

I don't mean a word in the text object sense; I mean a series of lower-case letters optionally beginning with a capital letter.  The optional capital letter is stymying me.

Here are some examples showing where I want to jump to, assuming the cursor starts at the end of the line:

```
quick brown fox
^     ^     ^

QuickBrownFox
^    ^    ^

Quick Brown Fox
^     ^     ^

quick_brown_fox
^     ^     ^
```

The closest I've come up with is `?\(\U\u\)\|\L?e+` – but that doesn't work with the capital letters.  I assume this is because \L matches before \U\u does.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This simple search works for all the examples you gave:

```
?\a\l\+
```

It matches any alphabetic character (upper or lower case), followed by any non-zero number of lower case characters.

Some examples of cases you didn't mention where I'm a little unclear what you want it to do:

```
match a lower case
MatchACapital
```

If you want it to match the single letter word a/A in both of these, then use a `*` instead of the `\+`:

```
?\a\l*
```

Comment: @andy-stewart I'm also unclear on whether you need the regexp to only *match* the first letter in the word. My answer moves the cursor in the way you describe, but matches the whole word.

Comment: Much iimprove, so amaze, wow

Comment: This however wouldn't work with `qui1ck brown fox` because of the number, but can bi fixed with something like `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]\+`

Comment: @user1685095 Yes! But again, it's not clear from the question what the OP actually would want it to do in that situation.

Comment: yes, absolutely. It's probably about programming. So digits inside a word are possible. But still that's a conjecture. Judging by his silence - he's already solved the problem by himself.

Comment: @Rich Thank you!  That's perfect.  My use case is modifying names (variables, classes, etc) when programming (also see my related question [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/12488/1643)).

Answer (score 0):

Although ugly this does what you need. At least in your example.
I think it could be simplified, but wouldn't bother to do so.
`\(\<\|\([a-z0-9]\?\(\( \|_\)\zs\|\zs\u\)\)\)`

With `very magic` `\v(<|([a-z0-9]?(( |_)\zs|\zs\u)))`

Comment: You're welcome!